# Decompiler supporting <>s from Java 6

Tags: java, types, decompiling

I have some class files that I have been decompiling, but I have found that the <>s next to my Sets, Lists, Iterators, etc. are not being shown in the output.

I have tried CFR, Procyon, JD-GUI, and FernFlower.

Upon attempting to recompile those classes, the compiler fails to do so mentioning a problem with the fact that my <>s are missing.

UPDATE: The <>s are shown in a Java 7 decompiled file, but not in a Java 6 one, as shown below:

The class in Java 7:
[image: Class in Java 7]

The class in Java 6:
[image: Class in Java 6]

Does anyone know why I might not be getting the <>s in the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Comment: Wait...it is not a duplicate. The <>s are retrieved by JD-GUI in Java 7 but not in Java 6

Comment: `<?>` would be incorrect and result in compile-time errors. Maybe `<Object>` might work.

Comment: Yes, I have attached pictures from JD-GUI of the class I had that was compiled in Java 6. I decompiled it, added the types, and recompiled it in Java 7; that is the first picture.

Comment: I'm guessing that the Java 7 javac was changed to add more annotations to the .class file.  One could, if they were really interested, dump equivalent 6 and 7 files and look for the difference.

Comment: @HotLicks: I doubt it. You could have annotations on public fields from the very beginning (Java5). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType%28%29 (since 1.5)

Comment: @HotLicks: I am crossing my fingers that is not the case...it will be interesting to see what happens after I use krakatau...

Comment: Ok I tried and failed, looks like HotLicks is probably right

Comment: Anyone have any other clues as to what this might be? If it was just type erasure, I'm pretty sure JD-GUI would be incapable of reconstructing the <>s in a Java 7 class like it did. What is also interesting, as noted by @Thilo, is that it doesn't preserve it on the right side. I'm clueless here, so any ideas will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why doesn't someone dump the files to find out?

Comment: [Mekanism is open source.](https://github.com/aidancbrady/Mekanism) Decompiling it is probably a waste of time.

Comment: I'm already aware of that @immibis, it is a version from Voltz :(
By the way I like your microblocks mod

Comment: @HotLicks just did, the interesting thing is that jdk7 and jdk6 both return no <>s, but I find that the compiler I used in the first picture does...I'll get back to you on this

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting the `<>`(s) because of [Type-Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) the first step of which is

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or `Object` if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

Comment: Your example above of Java 7 isn't legal Java 7 code.

Comment: What? I am serious...I did compile it in 7

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug in the decompiler. Are you using the same version of it in both cases?

For public fields (just like methods) the type annotations are preserved (because they are required to compile against the class).

But note that the annotation is not preserved on the right side of the assignment (because that is not part of the class signature).

Comment: So...if I were to edit the .class file and, say change the major/minor version from 50 to 51, do you think they would show?

Comment: No, this must work with even Java 5. Is it the same version of your decompiler stack for both cases (only difference the JDK version)?

Comment: I.E:
krakatau -d MYCLASS.class -o .
nano MYCLASS.j and change 50 to 51
krakatau -a MYCLASS.j -o .   ?